# What does <namespace>::class mean?

Tags: php, cakephp

In a [CakePHP Plugin documentation](http://cakephp-upload.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validation.html) there is the following code line: `$validator->provider('upload', \Josegonzalez\Upload\Validation\DefaultValidation::class);`

`\Josegonzalez\Upload\Validation\DefaultValidation` is the namespace, but I didn't understand the `::class`. Could someone explain it? I didn't find anything in PHP documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `class` constant simply returns the full name of the class (with namespace) as a string. So instead of passing as string to some method that requires it, you pass it the PHP way. It just looks nice, for example:

```
$validator->provider('upload',\Josegonzalez\Upload\Validation\DefaultValidation::class);
```

**AND**

```
$validator->provider('upload', '\Josegonzalez\Upload\Validation\DefaultValidation');
```

**Both Are Same**

And another advantage of this is that, if you need full class name several times in a single file.. say onto multiple method calls as a parameter. You can simply use it on the top & then only the classname will return the full name with namespace. like this:

```
use \Josegonzalez\Upload\Validation\DefaultValidation;

$validator->provider('upload', DefaultValidation::class);

//you can use it on other places as well, if required.
$someOtherClass->someOtherMethod(DefaultValidation::class);
```

So, in short, it reduces the number of characters you need to type, and makes your code look cleaner.

Comment: Also such usages can easily be changed via automatic refactoring, wich usually doesn't work well with strings (if at all).